# Returning a reified type using Data.Reflection in Haskell

Tags: haskell, reflection, types

This is a type question regarding Data.Reflection in Haskell. Reflection lets me take an Int and convert it to a type.

The functions f and g below are our best attempts at something reasonable, if you have a better way, let's have it!

For example, I could add numbers mod 41 by doing something like:

```
import Data.Reflection
import Data.Proxy

newtype Zq q i = Zq i deriving (Eq)
instance (Reifies q i, Integral i) => Num (Zq q i) where
   (...)
zqToIntegral :: (Reifies q i, Integral i) => Zq q i -> i
   (...)

f :: forall i . (Integral i) => i -> (forall q . Reifies q i => Zq q i) -> i
f modulus k = 
    reify modulus (\ (_::Proxy t) -> zqToIntegral (k :: Zq t i)
```

Then

```
>>:t (f 41 (31+15))
(f 41 (31+15)) :: Integral i => i
```

However, we would like to write a function like:

```
g :: forall i . (Integral i) => i -> (forall q . Reifies q i => Zq q i) -> Zq q i
g modulus k = 
    reifyIntegral modulus (\ (_::Proxy t) -> (k :: Zq t i)
```

and would like to get:

```
>>:t (g 41 (31+15))
(g 41 (31+15)) :: <some type info> => Zq q i
```

The difference is that we would like to be able to return a type that uses a reified int. At least one problem with the definition above is that the rank-2 type q is not visible to the return type.

The signature for reify in Data.Reflection is

```
reify :: a -> (forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> r
```

which as far we can tell requires the rank-2 type, and we don't know (if it is indeed possible) how to expose this type to the return type of the function.

Comment: The two ways I've seen it done are using a existentially qualified constructor or (my preferred way) continuation passing style. The latter requires changing the type of `g` to look more like `reifyItegral`: `g :: forall i j . (Integral i) => i -> (forall q . Reifies q i => Zq q i -> j) -> j`

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?  It's not possible AFAIK to expose the reified type, so instead can you tell use why you want to do so, and maybe someone can suggest an approach?

Comment: Like I said, what I'd like to do is pass in the modulus q as an integer, then use its reified type to add two numbers mod q, and return the answer as a Zq q i instead of an Int. As I said above, exposing the reified type was just one possible idea for a solution.

Comment: In the larger program, we have multi-parameter types, such as a vector of elements with both a dimension and a modulus as reified type parameters. We support multiple types of elements (not just Zq) and multiple arithmetic libraries, so we currently need a different function like f above for each combination. We would instead like to be able to create a 'partial type' and compose these functions. for example, we could choose to use Complex numbers and Repa or Zq and Vector using a composition of reifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lift a value to a type. But the type can't escape the function that does the lifting. That's just how rank 2 types work. Imagine if we could write `g` as you describe. Then, given some user-input value, we could get a `Zq` of varying qs at runtime.

But then what could we do with them?

If we have two `Zq` with the same `q`, we can add them. But we wouldn't *know* that they were the same q or not until runtime! And that's too late to check types, since we need to decide if we can add them or not at compile time. If you ignore the fact that `q` is in a phantom position, this is the same reason you can't have a function that returns an `Int` or a `Bool` at compile time, based on input (you can use an `Either`, of course).

So, as noted in the comment, you can do a few different things.

One thing you could do is just return the modulus (i.e. the value-level version of the `q`) at runtime, along with your result. Then you can always use it later.

That looks like this:

```
g :: forall i . (Integral i) => i -> (forall q . Reifies q i => Zq q i) -> (i,i)
g modulus k = reify modulus (\ m@(_::Proxy t) -> (zqToIntegral (k :: Zq t i), reflect m))
```

Another thing you can do is use existentials like so:

```
data ZqE i = forall q. ZqE (Zq q i)

h :: forall i . (Integral i) => i -> (forall q . Reifies q i => Zq q i) -> ZqE i
h modulus k = reify modulus (\ (_::Proxy t) -> ZqE (k :: Zq t i))
```

Now the only thing we can do with our ZqE is unpack it and return something else which also doesn't expose `q` directly in the type.

Note that we have no way to know that the `q` in any two `ZqE` are equal, so we can't do operations combining them directly, but rather should be creating them all under the same `reify` call. And this is not a bug, but a feature!